# Software to protect elderly people

Tags: help-desk, elderly

My grandfather always downloads the most scammy software you could possibly find in the web: - shady antivirusses - Help centres - Porn software and so on. I don't know how he gets it, he just asks me to remove it every then and now. I installed him firefox with ad & ublock, but that didn't got us any further.

I need a software that prevents him from installing new software and that only allows him to visit certain websites: or anything similiar to solve this problem.

Update:
My grandfather uses Windows 10, he needs some windows tools that are not available for linux (Or hard to install at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Porteus Kiosk](https://porteus-kiosk.org/) is a lightweight Gentoo-based Linux operating system which has been downscaled and confined to allow the use of one application only - the Firefox web browser. The browser has been locked down to prevent users from tampering with settings or downloading and installing software.

Porteus Kiosk is fast, small, free and secure. It's locked down by default. The only authorities capable of making changes are the kiosk owner (administrator) or the Porteus Team in case when kiosks are signed to the [automatic updates](https://porteus-kiosk.org/automatic-updates.html) service.

---

Windows 10 has a built-in [kiosk mode](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-kiosk-mode-windows-10-october-2018-update) feature, but kiosk mode in Windows 10 is transparently easy to circumvent if the user of Windows 10 has administrative privileges.

> To configure kiosk mode, do the following:
>
> 1. Open **Settings**.
> 2. Click on **Accounts**.
> 3. Click on **Family & other users**.
> 4. Under "Set up a kiosk," click the **Assigned access** button.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Click the **Get started** button.
>
>    [image]
> 6. Type a short, but descriptive name for the kiosk account.
>
>    [image]
> 7. Click the **Next** button.
> 8. Select a Microsoft Store app from the list.
>
>    [image]
>
>    **Info:** We're selecting Microsoft Edge, which includes additional
>      configuration options, but the settings for other apps may be
>      different.
> 9. Click the **Next** button.
> 10. Select the option that suits your environment. (In this guide, we're selecting "As a public browser," to configure a device that will
>       be used by guests to browse the internet.)
>
>     [image]
> 11. Click the **Next** button.
> 12. Type the web page address you want users to use for the home page, start page, and new tab page.
> 13. Specify the time before Microsoft Edge restarts the InPrivate session if no one is using the device.
>
>     [image]
>
>     [image: img]
> 14. Click the **Next** button.
> 15. Click the **Close** button.
>
> Once you've completed the steps, restart your computer to start in
>   kiosk mode.
>
> If you want to exit the experience to shutdown or restart the
>   computer, or access an administrator account, you'll need to use the
>   **Ctrl + Alt + Del** keyboard shortcut to bring up the Lock screen to access the sign-in screen and power options.

Comment: Thanks for the reccomendation: Is there also a solution for windows? I've updated the question

Comment: Windows 10 has a built-in [kiosk mode](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-kiosk-mode-windows-10-october-2018-update) feature, but kiosk mode in Windows 10 is transparently easy to circumvent  if the user of Windows 10 also has administrative privileges.

Comment: Good Idea. I could remove his admin-rights and activate this kiosk mode. Just whenever He would want to do something that requires any rights, he would have to ask me...

Answer (score 1):

I have a few elderly clients who use the computer for nothing other than web-based internet access. Obviously this requires a browser. For many of them, money is a concern as well.
In two cases thus far, I performed a clean Ubuntu and instructed the client about navigation: this is Firefox, this is Shutdown and that was about it.

If word processing is involved, Ubuntu installs with a good office-compatible suite.

Certainly Firefox and Ubuntu are not bullet-proof nor virus-proof, but you may find that a good bit of protection accompanies this type of installation.

Comment: That's a good Idea, the problem is, he knows (More or less) his way around windows. A change might be too difficult for him.

Comment: That's one aspect of Ubuntu that makes it work (for some), it's generally the same actions. Depending on the version of Ubuntu installed, the close window icon is in the same location. The file manager is a file folder, Firefox is the same icon. You can install an admin account for you, and a user account for him to secure things even more.